# How can I add a prefix to ALL my urls in django

Tags: python, django

I want to add a prefix to all my URLs in Django python (3.0.3)
so all my path that I defined in urls.py will start with "api/".
The prefix may be changed in the future so I want it to be dynamic as possible

Comment: Read [Including other URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply add prefix from `MyProject/MyProject/urls.py` with `include` function like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    #                                   ↓this↓ is app name  ↓this↓ is a namespace you can refer from your templates like this ex. {% url 'myapp:search' %} 
    path('api/', include(('myapp.urls', 'myapp'), namespace='myapp'))
]
```

and in your `MyProject/myapp/urls.py`(you dont have this file when creating your project, you can create this file)

```
from .views import Signup,Search
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', Signup.as_view(), name="signup"),
    path('search/', Search.as_view(), name="search"),
]
```

so every view in your `myapp` app will have `api/` prefix in their urls like `api/search/` or `api/signup/` and as @kyore mentioned you can read [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a nested prefix path() to the urlpatterns in your project/project/urls.py

beforre:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('yourapp/', include('yourapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

after:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('django_prefix/', include([
            path('yourapp/', include('yourapp.urls')),
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ])),
]
```

You can choose which should have the prefix or not.

And you should add the prefix to STATIC_URL, MEDIA_URL in your project/project/settings.py (to ensure the static and media files under the prefix too)

```
STATIC_URL = 'django_prefix/static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'django_prefix/media/'
```